# Need help calculating AVG of array values (minus the lowest)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, average, function-prototypes

So I have succeeded in confusing the hell out of myself in doing this. I am trying to get it to calculate the average of the weights entered into the array minus the lowest weight in the array. I'm using functions and somewhere along the line I confused myself with passing variables. It would be much appreciated if someone could give me a pointer and tell me if I'm way off base or not. Also how would I compare the values entered to a validation code? I have a line commented out that I was fiddling with, but never got working.

```
   #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int getWeight();
    int findLowest(int arrayWeight);
    double calcAverage(int weight);
    bool askToContinue();

    int main(){

        do{
            int weights = getWeight();
            double lowest = findLowest(weights);
            double average = calcAverage(weights);
        }
        while(askToContinue());
    }

    int getWeight() {

        //Variables
        int weights[5]; //array
        double enterWeight = 0;
        bool validAmount = false;


        //For loop to gather info and place amounts in an array
        cout << "Please enter the weights of the Tulbuks: " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
        {
            cin >> weights[counter];
            //validAmount = (weights[index] > 5) && (weights[index] <= 500);
        }

        //Test to redisplay the entered information
        cout << "Entered information: " << endl;
        for(int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
        {
            cout << "\nThe entered information for Tulbuk #" << (index+1) << " is: " << weights[index];
            cout << endl;
        }


        return -1;


        /*

        do
        {

            //Gather user input of amount of discs
            cout << "How many discs do you wish to purchase?" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 1,000,000" << endl;
            cin >> weights;
            cout << endl;
            validAmount = (weights > 5) && (weights <= 500);                              // Tests if the amount entered is valid
            if (!validAmount)                                                             // Prompts user amount entered was invalid
            {
                cout << "Invalid Amount. Please try again!" << endl;
            }
        }
        while(!validAmount);                                                              // Runs loop again if the amount entered was not valid



        return discs;

        */

    }

    int findLowest(int arrayWeight){

        int lowWeight = 999999;

        if(lowWeight > arrayWeight)
            {
                lowWeight = arrayWeight;
            }

        cout << arrayWeight;

        system("PAUSE");

        return arrayWeight;
    }

    double calcAverage(int weight){

        //Variables
        float avgWeight = 0;
        int sumWeight = 0;

        //Calls findLowest function to find lowest value
        int lowestWeight = findLowest(weight);

        //Calculates the average score


        return weight;
    }

    bool askToContinue()                                                                 // Asks the user if they want to continue. If yes, the loop restarts. If no, the program exits.
    {

        char userResponse = ' ';
        bool validInput = false;

        do
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Do you wish to continue?" << endl;
            cout << "Enter y for 'yes' or n for 'no'" << endl;
            cin >> userResponse;
            validInput = (userResponse == 'y') || (userResponse == 'n');
            if (!validInput)
            {
                cout << "Invalid response. Please try again!" << endl;
            }
        } while (!validInput);
        return(userResponse == 'y');
    }
```

Comment: Fyi, you can find the to-be-discarded lowest *while* you're calculating your summation before taking the average, then just subtract one from the item count and the lowest from the sum, do the division, and you're done. Or is your problem more an issue with your validation code than your computation algorithm(s)? (usually not a good sign, but it sure looks like it).

Comment: first off these functions have to communicate in some way.

Comment: If I didn't have to have them in functions I would've been fine. Understood the logic and how to go about it for the most part. The problem is that I have to use functions (school assignment) and it has to be broken up in the functions. The validation code has me really stumped because I am not 100% sure how to tell it to check each individual value in the array against it.

Comment: You have to pass the weights array to the other functions somehow. What happens if 999999 is a valid weight?

Comment: @NeilKirk It won't be able to once I figure out the validation code. The values have to be between 5 and 500 so that 999999 value will never be able to be reached (once I get that validation code working)

Comment: It's better not to hardcode arbitray constants such as these. You can either have a bool to say whether you've tested a condition yet or not, or use `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` to get the highest possible value.

Comment: @NeilKirk My main concern right now is getting the array passed correctly so that I can get the rest of the functions to work as needed. Hard coding a value for the sake of testing just works for someone who is learning C++

Comment: Create your weights array in the main function and pass it as a parameter to each function.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues, the first being you need to understand the data types you're working with. You should declare the array once and then pass around a pointer to that array. These are a better set of declarations and for convenience set up a constant for the number of weights.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int numWeights = 5;

void getWeights(int weights[]);
int findLowest(int weights[]);
double calcAverage(int weights[]);
bool askToContinue();

int main() {
    do {
        int weights[numWeights];
        getWeights(weights);
        double average = calcAverage(weights);
        cout << "Average: " << average << endl;
    }
    while (askToContinue());
}
```

getWeights was mostly ok, but use the passed in array.

```
void getWeights(int weights[]) {

    double enterWeight = 0;
    bool validAmount = false;


        //For loop to gather info and place amounts in an array
        cout << "Please enter the weights of the Tulbuks: " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
        {
            int weight;
            cin >> weight;
            while (weight < 5 || weight > 500) 
            {
                cout << "Invalid weight, should be between 5 and 500" << endl;
                cin >> weight;
            }
            weights[counter] = weight;
            //validAmount = (weights[index] > 5) && (weights[index] <= 500);
        }

        //Test to redisplay the entered information
        cout << "Entered information: " << endl;
        for(int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
        {
            cout << "\nThe entered information for Tulbuk #" << (index+1) << " is: " << weights[index];
            cout << endl;
        }
}
```

For findLowest you need to keep track of the lowest value and the lowest index. By remembering the index of the lowest value, you will make the average easier. Your 99999 magic number isn't needed since we know there will always be a lowest value in your set.  Start with index 0 and the first value. If you find something smaller, update the value and index. When the loop ends you'll have the first index of the lowest value. Note that the loops starts at 1 (the second item).

```
int findLowest(int weights[]) {
    int lowestVal = weights[0];
    int lowestIndex = 0;

    for (int i=1; i<numWeights; i++) {
        if (weights[i] < lowestVal) {
            lowestVal = weights[i];
            lowestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return lowestIndex;
}
```

For the average find the lowest index, add up all the weights but skip the index of the lowest, convert to double so you can get a good average and return the value.

```
double calcAverage(int weights[]) {
    int lowestIndex = findLowest(weights);
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numWeights; i++) {
        if (i != lowestIndex) {
            total += weights[i];
        }
    }
    return (double)total/(double)(numWeights-1);
}
```

Comment: One last thing - some of those parameters can be made const. And why divide by numWeights - 1?

Comment: The lowest weight is removed so there is one fewer item to divide by to caculate the average.

Comment: What happens if there is only 1 weight?

Comment: @JimW How would I fix this line here?  //validAmount = (weights[index] > 5) && (weights[index] <= 500);

Comment: @NeilKirk What purpose would that serve? They are going to do an experiment where they only measure 1 weight and throw it away?

Comment: @JimW Also wouldn't declaring the array outside the main make it a global variable?

Comment: It's the difference between good code and sloppy code. What if the number of weights is now entered by a user and the user enters 1? It should divide by 0 and explode?

Comment: @Paul2357 The array is still declared inside main. If you're trying to validate that the weight is between 5 and 500 put in a while loop that notifies the user the weight is wrong and inputs it again. I'll update getWeights above.

Comment: If the user entered 0 or -1 it would blow up even faster. If he wants to add error checking he can, but adding a bunch of error checking at the start of each method probably wouldn't help Paul's understanding.

Comment: 1 isn't error checking, it's a legitimate input value. Should sort function not work with array of size 1?

Comment: @JimW thanks for the help. I went through the code and made sure I understood everything!